# How to substitute a paragraph in file?

Tags: bash, sed, substitution, busybox

I want to change more than a line of a file. It is a CSS file and I want to swap out a section to another.

This is a snippet from the file:

```
    /*** Debugging ***/
    draw-button-bounding-rects: false;
    draw-button-rects: false;
    debug-touch-points: false;
    draw-reactive-areas: false;
}

MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape {
    /*** Label Setttings ***/
    label-margin-top: 0.6mm;
    label-margin-left-with-secondary: -1; /* not used, labels are centered horizontally */
    secondary-label-separation: 0;

    /*** Behaviour ***/
    touchpoint-horizontal-gravity: 32px;
    touchpoint-vertical-gravity: 20px;

    /*** Key Geometry ***/
    key-height-small: -1; /* unused */
    key-height-medium: 46px;
    key-height-large: 66px;
    key-height-x-large: 82px;
    key-height-xx-large: -1; /* unused */

    key-width-small-fixed: -1; /* unused */
    key-width-medium-fixed: 76px;
    key-width-large-fixed: 93px;
    key-width-x-large-fixed: 178px;
    key-width-xx-large-fixed: 244px;
    key-width-stretched-fixed: -1; /* unused */

    key-margin-left: 4px;
    key-margin-top: 0px;
    key-margin-right: 4px;
    key-margin-bottom: 12px;

    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;

    /*** Key Area Geometry ***/
    size: 854 -1;
}

MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Portrait {
```

If I use `sed -n '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/p'` it prints the correct paragraph but I want to substitute that with another. I have tried with `sed '/aStyle.Landscape {/}/s/aStyle.Landscape {/something/'` and similar but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` syntax you show is not entirely accurate; if it worked, then you must have used:

```
sed -n '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/p'
```

to print the lines from 'aStyle.Landscape' to the closing brace.

If you want to replace that paragraph, then you can do:

```
sed '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/c\
MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape {\
    /*** Label Setttings ***/\
    label-margin-top: 6.0mm;\
    label-margin-left-with-secondary: +1;\
    secondary-label-separation: 2;\
    ...\
}'
```

Note that each line in the replacement text except the last is followed by a backslash.

You might find it better to use a script file:

```
sed -f sed.script css.file
```

---

When I ran the script above, copied verbatim from this answer into a file 'xx', on the CSS fragment from the question (in 'xx.css') using `sh xx < xx.css`, the output I got was:

```
    /*** Debugging ***/
    draw-button-bounding-rects: false;
    draw-button-rects: false;
    debug-touch-points: false;
    draw-reactive-areas: false;
}

MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape {
    /*** Label Setttings ***/
    label-margin-top: 6.0mm;
    label-margin-left-with-secondary: +1;
    secondary-label-separation: 2;
    ...
}

MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Portrait {
```

You said you got everything on one line...I wonder how you ran the script?  If everything was 'on one line', I wonder if you do something like:

```
output=$(sed ... file.css)
```

followed by:

```
echo $output
```

This would flatten everything to one line (think of it as minimization).   The shape of the CSS would be preserved if you wrote instead:

```
echo "$output"
```

---

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456136/how-do-i-set-new-line-with-a-sed-using-c) shows how the 'flattening' problem arose.  There were two levels of shell interpretation (the shell that runs the `su` command, and the shell that is run by the `su` command), which is enough to give anyone a headache.  Doubling up the backslashes might be sufficient, but I'd create a script and run that.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. misspelled when i wrote it here. It is correct in the script. Thanks i will try it out but by the looks of it.. it should work.

Comment: It worked almost perfect.. exept that it couldn't hold the formating. It printed everything on one line. So now i need to find a way to make it use correct formating. The `\n` doesn't seam to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you to:

```
cat <<\EOF > new_para.txt
MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape
    /*** Label Setttings ***
    label-margin-top: 6.0mm;
    label-margin-left-with-secondary: +1;
    secondary-label-separation: 2;
    ...
}
EOF
> MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape
>     /*** Label Setttings ***
>     label-margin-top: 6.0mm;
>     label-margin-left-with-secondary: +1;
>     secondary-label-separation: 2;
>     ...
> }
sed -i -e '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/{/}/r new_para.txt' -e ';d}' file.css
```

If the replacement paragraph is of the same length and your using GNU sed, this would work to:

```
sed -i -e '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/{R new_para.txt' -e ';d}' file.css
```

N.B. The last method only works for a single replacement, unless each paragraph to be replaced (in order) is in the new_para.txt file. This does give the user a chance to tailor each replacement paragraph, a subtle but powerful difference.

EDIT:

To achieve the same result without an intermediate file:

```
cat <<\EOF | sed -i -e '/aStyle.Landscape {/,/}/{/}/r /dev/stdin ' -e ';d}' file.css
MImAbstractKeyAreaStyle.Landscape
    /*** Label Setttings ***
    label-margin-top: 6.0mm;
    label-margin-left-with-secondary: +1;
    secondary-label-separation: 2;
    ...
}
EOF
```

Comment: thanks but i wanted it in the same script and without extra files. The first by Jonathan worked but without formating. Just have to solve that and i am go.

Comment: ohh... now it starts to look intresting. I think i'll try this. (damit.. why can't my @ for ppl work)